# What to say in recipes to add the preparation to the previous one?

Tags: vocabulary

In traditional french cuisine, the cooking recipes can be written in a traditional way where an action follows the list of ingredients such as:

```
2 egg white        beat until foamy
20g sugar          add 
                   mix until thick
                   save for later

2 egg yolk         
40g sugar          mix until white, thick, fluffy
                   add to the saved preparation
```

I would like to know the proper way to say these two locutions 'save for later' and 'add to the saved preparation' in English.

Comment: It's an interesting way of laying out a recipe book. Perhaps not one which is common in the Anglo-Saxon world. I'd be interested in seeing a French recipe book which is presented like this. Are there any on google books (for example). The to locutions look correct to me.

Comment: Not much these days. This way of writing a recipe is very convenient because it is short and compendious. The main drawback is that it requires a minimal knowledge of cooking to know what `banchir`, `abaisser`, `corner` or `chevaler` mean. That said the french term `ajouter à l'appareil` literally `add to the device` means `add to the previously saved main preparation` and this is precisely this term that I am looking to say in English.

Comment: I do not know the terminology very well.  On cooking shows, they sometimes mix the dry ingredients in one bowl and wet ingredients in another.  At that point, they say something like, "Now mix the two preparations together." or "Now stir the dry ingredients into the liquid.".

Comment: The phrases that come to mind are "set aside" and "combine with".  For example, "Mix the milk and egg and *set them aside*.  Take the stewed fruit and *combine it with* the broth."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example for a soufflé the previous ingredients would be identified by what it is

> "add to the saved preparation" -> "fold into the egg whites"

Describing in this way, which seems to be usual amoung AmE recipe sites gives the author a chance to add additional instructions without being excessively long "fold in", "whisk in", "blend in", "combine in a food processor".

This recipe for [chocolate mousse](http://www.williams-sonoma.com/recipe/chocolate-mocha-mousse.html) uses "set aside"

The best idea is to write down your recipe, [here are some helpful hints](http://www.foodnetwork.co.uk/article/5-steps-writing-great-recipe.html), and have someone else make the recipe to see if it is understandable.